# Change behavior of Ctrl-C,Ctrl-F,Ctrl-V in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Most programs copy selected text (say `selectedText1`), open textbox and paste buffer in search when  `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-F`, `Ctrl-V` hotkeys are pressed. IntelliJ decided change this behavior to "more efficient". `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-F` copy-paste highlighted text in a search box.

I end up pressing Ctrl-C, Ctrl-F, Ctrl-V -> `selectedText1selectedText1` 0 results -> Backspace several times -> `selectedText` -> too many results, because `selectedTextProcessor` and `selectedText2` are included.

This breaks workflow.

AutoHotKey script to replace ^F with ^F, ^A, Backspace is my current workaround. 
Is there a way to tell intelliJ that I want conventional ^c,^f,^v behavior? For instance enable "if ^F,^V are pressed, first ^V is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way to do that. The whole point is this way is more efficient.

Your claim about "most programs" and "conventional behaviour" is spurious. Most that I use will default to searching the text on the clipboard, if there isn't already text selected in the current window.